# Comparison in VHDL when using numeric_std.All

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, hardware

I have encountered a problem in VHDL. I am working on an entity. I have only included the libraries STD_LOGIC_1164 and NUMERIC_STD. I did a comparison between two signals A and B with two different configurations:

Definitions (At their associated suitable locations):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.All;

signal A   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
signal B   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
```

First Configuration:

```
report "A = "              & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(A)));
report "B(15 downto 0) = " & image(to_integer(unsigned(B(15 downto 0))));

if A=B(15 downto 0) then
    report "Equal";
else
    report "Un-Equal";
end if;
```

Second Configuration:

```
report "A = "              & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(A)));
report "B(15 downto 0) = " & image(to_integer(unsigned(B(15 downto 0))));

if unsigned(A)=unsigned(B(16 down to 0)) then
    report "Equal";
else
    report "Un-Equal";
end if;
```

As you can see I have only included the cast function "unsigned" in the second case. The simulation reports when A and B(15 downto 0) are equal is like this:

For the first statement:

```
A=1000
B(15 downto 0)=1000
Un-Equal
```

For the second statement:

```
A=1000
B(15 downto 0)=1000
Equal
```

So the second statement works perfectly. What is the reason for this? Also if the first statement is wrong why simulator does not output an error?

Comment: I assume the range for B in your first configuration is a typo and should be (15 downto 0) ?

Comment: `& image(to_integer(unsigned(B(15 downto 0))));` Where is the function image defined? Or did you mean `integer'image(to_integer....` This question doesn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's an extraneous space between `down` and `to` in the if statement condition of your second configuration. With the B range (16 downto 0) both return unequal. If the first configuration were 16 downto 0 and the second 15 downto 0 you'd get your results.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators "Two composite values of the same type are equal if and only if for each element of the left operand there is a *matching element* of the right operand and vice versa, and the values of matching elements are equal, as given by the predefined equality operator for the element type."

Comment: As shown both configuration return unequal with an MCVE.

Comment: This is not an exact copy-paste from my code. I simplified the syntax. I thought it may be a known issue. I mean if you are using numeric_std then you probably should not use comparison between STD_LOGIC_VECTOR?? Am I right?

Comment: For equality or in equality there's no difference. For ordering (magnitude) relational operators, std_logic_vector is string comparison based on element values (std_ulogic) while numeric_std ordering is based on the binary value. numeric_std also defines "=" between signed and unsigned and integers (naturals).